# How do I set the "contact" and "location" for a Brother laser printer?

Tags: printer

I have a Brother HL-4570CDW laser printer.   It stores its location as well as contact information for the printer administrator in the printer memory.   The location shows up in print dialogs when I print to this computer.   That information is also listed on the printer web page (highlighted with red box):

[image]

I moved this printer out of the basement and I would like to change the location.  It would also be nice to set the contact.

I must have managed to set the location before, but now I can't figure out how to set it.   I have:

- Looked through all the settings on the web interface
- Looked through all the menus on the printer LCD screen
- Consulted the product manuals on the brother website. (I searched through them for "contact" and "location".   I found nothing relevant.)
- Searched the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Brother technical support.  They were eventually able to locate the setting for me.   In the web interface it is under:  **Administrator Settings** -> **Configure Password** -> **Configure Password (admin)**.  Then the page is titled "Password & Contact" and has a form for setting the contact and location:

[image]

It also appears that you can get there slightly more directly through **Network Configuration** -> **Password & Contact**.